# What are the origins of electronegativity?

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, elements

Now, this might sound to be a chemistry oriented question. Today in physics class, we discussed bonds and [electronegativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity), and I wondered why it does originate. I would appreciate it if someone explains why atoms have electronegativity regarding the structure and the role quantum numbers play in it.